# Ubuntu 12.04 is hogging the battery power

Tags: 12.04, icons, battery

I was using my computer the other day on my kitchen side. I wanted to move to the sofa and so I took the power cable out. I took about ten seconds to get to the sofa and plug it in and when I checked the power icon it said it would take 15 mins to charge fully. 15 mins! 
I don't know how it would that long to charge. I **used to have** Windows Vista (That one day it got to the login screen and the option was 'Other User') and it was fine.

How can I stop it doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Jupiter.

It is designed to improve battery life of a portable Linux computer by integrating with the operating system and changing parameters of the computer based on battery or powered connection.

You can install Jupiter by typing the following commands.

Open a terminal window (alt+ctrl+t) and type

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install jupiter`

i advise you to check out this "[link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks)" about Power Saving Tweaks.

You can also install powertop which is a Linux tool to find out what is using power on a laptop. you can get it "[here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/powertop)".

Comment: Thank you very much. I will install it later on in the week as my charger has died. I am getting a new one.