# Why does my laptop overheat and discharge faster in Ubuntu than Windows?

Tags: battery, overheating

I am new to Linux. I have a Dell Inspiron 15 with a 1st generation Intel Core i3 and Ubuntu 12.10.

My laptop gets heated quickly which doesn't happen on Windows. Also the battery is discharged faster than in Windows. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/9820/how-do-i-debug-an-overheating-problem?rq=1 and for battery life http://askubuntu.com/questions/232379/ubuntu-12-04-is-hogging-the-battery-power/232616#232616

Comment: Although I don't understand the internals enough to change them, I believe it has to choose with the optimizations done in the linux kernel.  You can either optimize for 1)speed or for 2)battery usage/power consumption.  The linux kernel being optimized for speed often outputs a lot of heat.  You can install specific software to help but thats the gist

Comment: @john Does your computer overheat then shutdown or just get really hot?

Answer (score 1):

most probably installing the correct VGA driver can reduce overheating. To install correct VGA driver

#### you need to do some simple things if your using ubuntu 12.10

1. first go to software center and type drivers.
2. in there find additional drivers. and install it.
3. after installation complete open it. it will search drivers for your VGA card. **warning! do not close it. because additional drivers not working properly in 12.10 so once you close you cannot find it anywhere. then you must remove it and re-install it again through software center.**
4. install all available VGA drivers for your machine.
5. after installation complete it will ask you to restart. you done!.
6. after restart go to Settings >  Details there you can see your VGA name and type.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in more than one place. When tempted to do so, this means that either: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), or (3) the answer should really be a comment, (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it is due to having several graphic cards enabled simultaneously, usually intel + (Nvidia | ATI). I have this same problem.

You can try to disable one of the graphic cards. You could find additional information in this blog dedicated to [Linux hybrid graphics](http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com.es/).

Answer (score -2):

This is kernel issue. You can reinstall a kernel of your choice through SW manager in ubuntu. I faced the same problem with ubuntu in my laptop and fixed it by reinstalling the same karnel that RHEL 6.4 uses. Hope the same will work fine for you.

Comment: Could you clarify what version of the kernel should be installed?

Comment: This answer is too generic. "I blame the kernel, reinstall it" will usually install the very same kernel. So, please, be specific.